# Which is the largest train in terms of passengers?

Tags: trains, factoids

I wondered which passenger train has the largest capacity while travelling in a busy double decker double traction Ouigo train (low cost French high speed train), which according to Wikipedia offer 1260 seats.

<strike>I guess you can get different answers for  inter city trains with compulsory reservation and commuter ones, and for the latter, the official max capacity and the actual one.</strike>
EDIT : to make this question more answerable, I now ask only about seat capacity on a train with compulsory reservation (or at least with an enforced limit in the number of passenger). And I like to limit to regularly scheduled service, not in records like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_trains#Passenger_2).

This [forum post](http://www.indiamike.com/india/indian-railways-f10/how-many-passengers-are-on-a-train-t53263/) about Indian trains give higher figures, counting "unreserved seats". Are there enforced limits on theses coaches ?

I believe that technical limitations (especially regarding  platform length) should make this question answerable.

Comment: What is "a train"? Note that "traditionally", trains used to be very flexible things that consisted of one or more engines, and *a variable number of cars of different types/sizes*. In modern times, this has decreased a bit, owing to the increased use of multiple unit trains, but even these are often designed to be used in such a way that two or more of these multiple unit trains can be connected to form one even longer train.

Comment: also its worth considering whether this is *officially* or *unofficially*

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Even if sounds trivial to simply attach an extra waggon to a traditional train to increase capacity, the way railway networks (tracks and stations) are built, you will soon run into practical limits due to the length of platforms and passing loops. In West European countries, passenger trains are usually limited to about 14 waggons.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: It seems then, the question should be reworded to something like "Assuming the length of platforms and other infrastructure in <location>, what is the largest (in terms of passengers) train that could be assembled based upon existing rolling stock?" To me, the question for "the largest <something>", where <something> is something that can be modularly assembled, does not make any sense.

Comment: @pnuts Unlikely. The trains operating on the Northern Line have only an official capacity of 662 passengers (seated and standing).

Comment: Article that gives 3500 in India: http://www.dnaindia.com/mumbai/report-western-railway-plans-to-reduce-seats-for-increased-standing-capacity-1516585 But I have no idea if that is a big train according to their norms.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I presume we should limit it to trains which have been actually operated, i.e. the largest total passenger capacity of a set of rolling stock that has actually operated as a unit in passenger service.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Given that even those can be spontaneously modified on a daily basis, I am not convinced this is practically answerable. For instance, [German railway even offers charter trains](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/bahnbusiness/buchung/charterzug/charterzuege.shtml). They state "Depending on the number of travelers, the length of the train can be individually adjusted - depending on resources and train type, a train can take up to 800 persons. If you are a larger group, contact us."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Spontaneously? Are you sure you understand the meaning of that word? As explained before, there are multiple constraints (from available traction and rolling stock to block length and platform size) on how a train can be assembled, this is not something a random mechanic decides when showing up at work. The fact trains are modular is neither here nor there.

Comment: @Relaxed: Spontaneously as in without ordering or constructing any new or custom rolling stock. Let's not get lost in nitpicking on vocabulary. My point is simply that while a question such as "What is the largest passenger plane/bus in service?" is probably answerable, the analogous question about a train does not make as much sense because a train is a variable-size collection of vehicles. Add to that that the question is ill-defined by making no statement about seats vs. standing passengers, or other factors (three children on two adult seats = larger capacity?), and you get the ...

Comment: ... archetype of an open-ended list question where everyone adds their take on "rather long trains" that ought to be mentioned and might be among the "largest", passenger-wise.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Unlike some of your last comments, that's not a nitpick, you got all worked up on the building part but it seems you fundamentally misunderstand how railway networks work. Train composition is not something someones decides spontaneously or improvises on a daily basis and it's certainly not open-ended. Even day-to-day changes need to be planned. You're now reaching to silliness (three children on two seats, how is that specific to trains or related to their modular nature?) as your initial objection turned out to be uninformed but the question is not that hard to understand.

Comment: My Boston commuter train I take every morning packs about 1500. Not a pleasant experience !

Comment: @Relaxed: While the composition of trains can change on a daily basis, of course those changes are normally planned several months ahead. (And note that even that is not true in all cases - for instance, replacement trains that are used when the original train has technical issues are composed on short notice for obvious reasons.) "how is that specific to trains or related to their modular nature?" - I did not claim it was, did I? I am just illustrating how open to interpretation and thus unanswerable the question is.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well if that's not what you claimed and you really did not mean “spontaneously on a daily basis”, then I don't know what your point is or how any of this makes the question unanswerable. Except perhaps minor quibbles about standing passengers vs. seats and potential charter trains, I don't see any cogent objection in all this.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will try to narrow down this question.

Comment: This would be a good example question for the "Railways & Railroads" proposal on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105759/railways-and-railroads?referrer=9Y-betkg4nIRFW0MkXy75w2

Comment: @Nick C : OK, done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For The Netherlands there is evidence of a driven combination for 1411 seats for passengers, found on the forum of the [Dutch Railways](https://forum.ns.nl/off-topic-32/langste-trein-nederland-13084/index1.html#post82074). The train contained 2 times a VIRM4 (391 + 16 seats) and one time a VIRM 6 (571 + 26 seats), where the second number is the number of folding seats. That combination is not common, though. Two times a VIRM 6 containing 1194 seats is driven daily throughout The Netherlands.

There were two records on longest train with passengers coaches in The Netherlands and [Belgium](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-passenger-train/). The first one contained 60 carriages, the second one 70 carriages (of which 5 without seats). I'm not completely sure how much seats there were, but it should be roughly 60 per carriage, giving roughly 3900 seats.

Comment: Even if this is slightly more than the train mentioned in the question, I would guess that you are still way behind the actual 'highest capacity train' and that you are more likely to find candidates in the most densely populated areas of Asia.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Not anymore I guess, as the question has been restated to seats of an actual driven train.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

According to this poster, it's the E4 shinkansen in Japan. It's a double-decker high speed train that carries up to 1634 passengers.

Answer (score 1):

[Z 8100](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_8100) operating on Paris RER-B has a capacity of 850 passengers, or 1700 passengers when 2 units are coupled.

[MI 09](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/MI_09) operating on RER-A has a capacity of 1300 (single unit) / 2600 (double unit) passengers.

Comment: Those numbers are both including pitches. The number of people being able to sit is much lower: 948 for Z 8100. I can't find the number of MI 09.

Comment: @renzeee: 948 in the MI 09 according to this wiki article.

Comment: @corentin: which article?